# Append custom options if no results found in bootstrap dropdown(select picker)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am using bootstrap search [dropdown](https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Filterable-Bootstrap-Dropdown-Select-Bootstrap-Select.html) which is working fine. I want to attach/append few other options to the same dropdown incase search result shows "no result matches".

Here is the code that I am using for its bind:

This is selectlist

```
   <select id="ddlselectPicker" onchange="return AppendData();" data-live-search="true"></select>
```

I am using ajax to bind this Item:

```
function AppendData()
{
var ddlCustomers = $("#ddlselectPicker");
        ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0" disabled = "disabled">Loading.....</option>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: $('#hfUrl').val(),
            data: '{}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: false,
            success: function (response) {
                ddlCustomers.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Select</option>');
                $.each(response, function () {
                    ddlCustomers.append($("<option></option>").val(this['Prckey']).html(this['Name']));


                });

            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            }
        });
}
```

It automatically shows me "no results found" in case I don't et results from type and search. But instead of this, I need to show another 3 options in the same dropdown which should say 1)"Others" 2)"Self Employed", 3)"Free Lancer"

I am trying this but not able to achieve:

```
 $(".dropdown-menu open >input").on('keydown', 'li.no-results', function () {
            $("#selectpicker")
                .append('<option>Others</option>')
                .append('<option>Self Employed</option>')
                .append('<option>Retired</option>')
                .selectpicker('refresh');
            //You can also call AJAX here to add the value in DB
        });
```

Please also have a look on image which I get after I get no results found[image]

This is what I ahve tried and which appended the new options in case no result found But now I am not able to retrieve the previous filter

```
 $(".bs-searchbox >input").keyup(function () {
            debugger;
            var searchTerm = "";
            var ddlCustomers = $("#ddlselectPicker");
            var list = $(".dropdown-menu .inner li:eq(0)").text();
            debugger;
            if (list.indexOf("No results matched") != -1) {
                ddlCustomers.empty();
                ddlCustomers.append('<option value="Others">Others</option>');
                ddlCustomers.append('<option value="Self Employed">Self Employed</option>');
                ddlCustomers.append('<option value="Retired">Retired</option>');
                ddlCustomers.selectpicker('refresh');
            }
            else {

                 }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you add them in the `success` callback if `response.length === 0`? Or, if this conflicts with the `bootstrap` behaviour, you could just add them from server side.

Comment: Actually this search is client side. all the records in select are bind at load time. So, I can't check using callback in response.

Answer (score 4):

I have a good program. This code made my problem simpler.
Have a look

styles

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="assets/vendor/fonts/circular-std/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/fonts/fontawesome/css/fontawesome-all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap-select/css/bootstrap-select.css">
```

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id="branch" multiple>
        <option>B.Tech</option>
        <option>M.Tech</option>
        <option>Ph.D</option>
</select>
```

jQuery script

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
noneResultsText: 'No result found <button class="btn btn-dark" onclick=(add_opt(this))>Add new option</button>'
}); 

function add_opt(event){
var value = $(event).parents('div').siblings('.bs-searchbox').find('input').val();
$(event).parents('div').siblings('.selectpicker').append($("<option></option>").text(value)).val(value);
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

mm.. 
if they are always the same you could always add them and just hide them using a CSS display none.

[code pen example](https://codepen.io/danbete/pen/pOOepO)

```
<select class="no-results">
<option value='Others'>Others</option>
<option value='Self Employed'>Self Employed</option>
<option value='Retired'>Retired</option>
</select>

<select class="with-results">
<option value='test'>Test1</option>
<option value='test'>Test2</option>
<option value='Others'>Others</option>
<option value='Self Employed'>Self Employed</option>
<option value='Retired'>Retired</option>
</select>
```

CSS

```
   select.with-results option[value='Others'],
select.with-results option[value='Self Employed'],
select.with-results option[value='Retired'] {
 display:none;
}
select.no-results  option[value='Others'],
select.no-results option[value='Self Employed'],
select.no-results option[value='Retired']{
 display:block;
}
```

Comment: have you add value attributes?
check this code pen:
https://codepen.io/danbete/pen/pOOepO